# Editing specific sentence in a paragraph using CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So basically so far I have tried using a span and h2 tag around the sentence but that separated the sentence from the rest of the paragraph. I have also tried using pseudo elements such as ::first-line and that seems to just not work at all. I couldn't really find anything online to help me besides the solutions I mentioned but they didn't work. Any ideas?

Just to Clarify, I need the sentence to still remain a part of the paragraph, I am trying to bolden it (yes I tried the strong tag still separated my sentence) but I also would like to learn how to target specific words and sentences in a paragraph for future use.

I am also making this application in ReactJs if that makes a difference.

HTML

Who We Serve

```
    <p>
      We are passionate for the local church. Our mission is to come
      alongside the local church to help them empower, equip, and release
      more of God’s people to do the work of the ministry.
    </p>

    <img
      src={WhoWeServe}
      alt="Lanier Family"
      className=" lol__WhoWeServe-image2"
    />
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    .lol__WhoWeServe-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block;

  margin-left: 2rem;
  padding-left: 0rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.lol__WhoWeServe-heading h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-weight: 800px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;

  color: black;
}

.lol__WhoWeServe-heading p {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: 50px;
  
  
  

  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;

  color: #525252;
}

.lol__WhoWeServe-heading > p {
font-weight: 800;
font: 16px;
color: black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If executed correctly the **span** element will allow you to style specific text within another element. The [**span** element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) is used as an inline container unlike a p or H tag that are block level and will cause your sentence to break. Run the code snippet below to see how powerful it is once you add a few classes and CSS to change the style of certain words within one sentence. Hope you can recycle this example to solve your problem.

```css
div {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.text-drop-cap {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #a3b2a4;
}

.text-bold {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span class="text-drop-cap">L</span>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="text-uppercase">consectetur</span> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <span class="text-bold">tempor incididunt</span> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Edgar, unfortunately the span element is still causing it to separate from the rest of the paragraph even after trying it again. I would share a screen shot but I am still new to stack overflow so the website won't let me.

Comment: @JeremyMartinez Sorry to hear that you are still experiencing the issue. Can you edit your question and use the HTML tool in the editor to add the complete code so users can run the code snippet to replicate your issue. You can also use a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) or CodePen (https://codepen.io/) to paste your current code. P.s. Consider simplifying the code to basic HTML/CSS since you are using React.